# mysql2 MULTI_STATEMENTS and error reporting

Tags: ruby, mysql2

I submit multiple database queries using a single call to `mysql2` client. The client is configured using `Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS` flag.

If one of the queries has a syntax error, I want the call to fail, but currently it succeeds unless an error is in the first statement.

My test code is below. Is there a way to accomplish this while still using multi-statement queries (and not sending each query separately)?

```
require 'mysql2/em'

def database
  @database ||= Mysql2::EM::Client.new(flags: Mysql2::Client::MULTI_STATEMENTS)
end

EM.run {
  database.query('select rand(1);bad syntax;').callback {|rs|
    rs.each {|r|
      p r
    }
    EM.stop
  }.errback {|e|
    p e
    EM.stop
  }
}
```